# How to fire appium command in terminal using java in Mac?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, terminal, appium, appium-ios

I wanted to start appium server programatically using java in Mac.
I am able to open terminal with following code:

```
  String cmd= "osascript -e \"tell app \\\"Terminal\\\" to activate\"";
    List<String> command1=new ArrayList<String>();
    command1.add("/bin/sh");
    command1.add("-c");
    command1.add(cmd);
    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(command1);
    pb.start();
```

But I am not able to send any command in terminal.

Please suggest any solution.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 It seems you are trying to open Terminal app, which is not required rather you can try this: 
 There are many ways to do start appium programatically:
 1. Create a text file and write command: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; /usr/local/bin/appium & -g /tmp/app.log --command-timeout 90 and save this file with .sh extension say test.sh and give executable permission to this file like chmod +x test.sh
 2. Now you can execute this command using your java code like: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<PATH_TO_FILE>/test.sh");

Thats all. You can check if appium is running by browsing localhost:4723, 
if you are writing further tests, you need to wait until appium server is started in your code.
```

Comment: Hi @Pankaj Katiyar, I tried with your suggestion. No success for me. But I did this using robotil jar.

Comment: quite strange, I am using this way from last 1 year.. can you share the error what you are getting??? Also are you using Mac ?